# Rupee symbol not rendering properly on invoice pdf in magento

Tags: magento

Rupee currency symbol not rendering properly in my invoice pdf.. It shows tags like this `**&#x20B9;**`. Please someone help me out this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could try changing the font of the invoice. That can be done by making local versions of these files:

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php 
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php

Put them to:

```
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php 
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php
```

Then edit functions _setFontRegular, _setFontBold and _setFontItalic.

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir(). /lib/LinLibertineFont/**yourfont**.ttf);
```

Also you have to put yout TTF font file to the lib/LiLibertineFont folder. You could try font like DejaVuSans. That worked for Nigerian Naira currency at least.

Answer (score 0):

the solution for this problem is very simple

just click on system --> Magnage currency -->symbols --> Copy your symbol like in my case "₹" and save...

My pdf problem solved with this :)

Hope this help

Comment: this did not change my problem. I still have same issue as above. Not Working in invoice pdf, but working fine in all other cases.